# Is it a pure function?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have following function:

```
  def timestamp(key: String)
  : String
  = Monoid.combine(key, Instant.now().getEpochSecond.toString)
```

and wanted to know, if it is pure or not? A pure function for me is, given the same input returns always the same output. But the function above, given always the same string will returns another string with another time, that it is in my opinion not pure.

Comment: to make it pur, you could pass the time as a argument to the function `def timestamp(key: String, time: Date)`

Comment: Think about it this way, if you'd substitute the method call for the resulting value, would your program behave the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not pure by any definition I know of. A good discussion of pure functions is here: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/fp-book/definition-of-pure-function. In Alvin's definition of purity he says:

> A pure function has no “back doors,” which means:
>
> ...
>
> It cannot depend on any external I/O. It can’t rely on input from files, databases, web services, UIs, etc; it can’t produce output, such as writing to a file, database, or web service, writing to a screen, etc.

Reading the time of the current system uses I/O so it is not pure.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, it is not a pure function as it returns different result for the same arguments. Mathematically speaking it is not a function at all.

Definition of [Pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) from Wikipedia

> 1. The function **always evaluates the same result value given the same argument value(s)**. The function result value cannot depend on any hidden information or state that may change while program execution proceeds or between different executions of the program, nor can it depend on any external input from I/O devices (usually—see below).
> 2. Evaluation of the result does not cause any semantically observable side effect or output, such as mutation of mutable objects or output to I/O devices (usually—see below).